# Controlling SMPS with SSR (Blinking SMPS)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, solid-state-relay, leakage-current

I want to control AC for Meanwell RS-25-3.3 using SSR-25DA.
When SSR is off mode the SMPS keep blinking as in hiccup mode, I think.
I don’t think leakage current from SSR is too high to trigger this mode.

No connection for output SMPS.

I try using RS-25-5, the behavior is same blinking.
I try using RS-25-12, the behavior is okay.

Connection is as: Main AC -> Mechanical on off switch -> SSR -> SMPS

Any idea why this happen?

[image: SSR-25DA spec]

[image: Meanwell RS-25-3v3 spec]
[image: voltage measured at output]

Comment: Welcome! _”hiccup mode, I think. I don’t think leakage current from SSR is too high to trigger this mode.”_ Please refrain from it and rather measure what’s happening. What’s the voltage on the secondary side of the SSR in this configuration?

Comment: @winny It is moving constantly around 10VAC to 30VAC. Supply is 240VAC

Comment: Show with an oscillogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of SSR leakage current.

The SSR leaks up to 4mA, and SMPS leaks only up to 2mA.

Therefore the SMPS input cap charges up slowly to a voltage level which starts it running. But it will only run with the energy stored in the cap so it discharges and voltage drops rapidly to a level where the SMPS turns off.

And then the leakage starts charging it again, repeating the cycle.

Comment: But I still dont understand why it is not happen at RS-25-12. The leakage current has the same spec.

Really hope at least it state min current to turn it on

Comment: I have no other explanation except for toleraces. It's a different individual unit. Both th SSR and PSU have their individual leakages, which will vary between different SSRs and PSUs. The data sheet just guarantees it does not exceed a certain limit.